Stop apps/websites changing your volume
I have searched and searched this issue and came across a number of "solutions" that do not actually do what I need done.
I tend to keep my volume on my PC muted until I need it, as I have a speaker hooked up and do not want noise blaring out if I start up a new page or app.  The problem is that either an app or a website or even windows itself automatically un-mutes the volume and often turns the volume to 100%.
All of the solutions that I have found focus on restricting the volume to a certain level.  That's not what I need.  What I am looking for is some way to stop apps/websites/windows changing the volume state/level.
Updates:

It seems that when I go on to a website such as YouTube my system unmutes audio and raises the volume to 100%. I presume that is my browser doing that rather than the website itself.

I am running Opera (version 114.0.5282.102) on Windows 11 (all updates added).

I have checked and Chrome, Edge and Vivaldi as well, and they all behave the same way.

I have completely reinstalled Windows from scratch (removing all my files and settings and this still happens.  I have also ran a full Malewarebytes scan and also a full Iobit Malware Fighter scan which both came back with zero results, so I don't think that I am infected.


How do I prevent audio doing this? I want the audio to stay muted when I mute it, and not automatically raise the volume beyond what I have set.

Websites cannot control volume or muting. Only “desktop applications” can do that.

What browser, on which OS? Can you give an example of a web site that you believe has changed volume??

When the volume suddenly changes, that's usually the result of changing the audio configuration. For example, if you have wired speakers, a USB headset and a Bluetooth boombox, Windows stores volume settings for each configuration. E.g. you can have the sound muted for the headphones, but unplug those and the volume settings change. Another source of volume manipulation are headphone or gaming peripheral software, which often implement additional sound control features which override Windows settings - for better or worse.

@user2575912, please edit the question (the button is directly below the question) to add all that information, and remove the comments.

Your question needs to have all this information in it. Please use the EDIT button to add all the requested information to your question. Also, considering your problem description and taking it at face value, you should consider that your computer may be infected with malware of some sort.

Given that you've tried other browsers and they behave the same, it is not the browser, and it is probably not the site either.  Check your audio device drivers. Do you use switch between multiple audio output devices, like headphones, integrated or desk speakers, etc? Are the audio output devices connected via Bluetooth? If so, disconnect all but one audio output device and disable Bluetooth and test again.

This feels like some sort of driver/helper app issue. Something is trying to be helpful but is failing utterly. Please also look at how I have edited your post. This is better than simply copying comments into the body. The goal isn't for you to hold a conversation with us in the question. The goal is to make your post complete to the point where the complete issue and all its details can be fully understood simply by reading the post. Clarifying questions here give you additional info to add to the question.
